# Python Pandas adding two dataframes SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, slice

I don't understand why I am getting the dreaded warning when I am doing exactly as instructed by the official documentation.

We have a `dataframe` called `a`

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Tom',1],
                         ['Tom',1], 
                         ['Dick',1], 
                         ['Dick',1], 
                         ['Harry',1],
                         ['Harry',1]], columns = ['Col1', 'Col2'])

a

Out[377]: 
    Col1  Col2
0    Tom     1
1    Tom     1
2   Dick     1
3   Dick     1
4  Harry     1
5  Harry     1
```

First we create a "holder" `dataframe`:

`holder = a`

Then we create a subset of `a`:

```
c = a.loc[a['Col1'] == 'Tom',:]

c

Out[379]: 
  Col1  Col2
0  Tom     1
1  Tom     1
```

We create another subset `d` which will be added to (a *slice* of) the previous subset `c` but once we try to add `d` to `c`, we get the warning:

```
d = a.loc[a['Col1'] == 'Tom','Col2']

d

Out[389]: 
0    1
1    1


c.loc[:,'Col2'] += d

C:\Users\~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:494: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong because I use this logic very often (coming from R where everything is not a darn `object`)

Comment: Could you add a complete and reproducible code example (i.e. a fully self-standing code example that produces this `SettingWithCopyWarning` when run)?

Comment: Have you read some of the resources on the subject? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/11301900. As an aside, if you want to get a subset of the DataFrame consisting of multiple columns you can simply do `df[['col_1', 'col_3']]` instead of using `.loc[]`.

Comment: Also, could you share a [mcve]? I'm not managing to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After noticing a different issue, I found a solution.

Whenever you say

`dataframe_A = dataframe_B`

you need to proceed with caution because Python, it seems, joins these two dataframes by the hip, so to speak. If you make changes to `dataframe_B` your `dataframe_A` will also change!

I understand just enough to fix the problem by using `.copy(deep=True)` where python will create a full and **independent** copy so that you can make changes to one without affecting the other one.

On further investigation, and for those interested, it apparently has to do with "pointers" which is a slightly complicated coding concept with a scope beyond this specific question.